# regarding the output of a query given below

Tags: c

This program gives output as 4 3 2 1.
Why does it stop at 1 when no condition is given for i?
Do main(10) and main(i) differ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    static int i = 5;
    if (--i){
        printf("%d ", i);
        main(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: When `i == 0` the if statement evaluates to `false` and the program hops down the recursion stack and terminates

Comment: Also, the `i` you pass to `main` as an argument is ignored. `int main()` has no arguments defined, so you can't access any. The `static int i` retains its value between calls and is available in all recursions (although recursing `main` is frowned on).

Comment: Did you write this code, or did someone give it to you as a puzzle?  If you wrote this code, please don't write code like this ever again: it's so unnecessarily confusing it might as well be meaningless.

Comment: @SteveSummit Well this was a output question given in geeks for geeks website. I didn't write the code.Thank you very much sir.

Comment: @ThirumuruganR This may be unfair, but based on what I've seen there (which isn't much), that site might as well be named IdiotsForIdiots.  Evidently anyone can post anything there, and most of the posters don't really know what they're doing, so the useful, accurate content is scattershot at best.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You actually have a condition:

`if (--i)` is equivalent to `if(--i != 0)`

Comment: and in `main(i)` the `i` is not used

Answer (score 1):

**Equivalent code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    static int i = 5;
    i = i - 1;
    if (i != 0){
        printf("%d ", i);
        main(i);
    }
}
```

**Stack trace**

```
i=5, print 4, call main(4) 
    i=4, print 3, call main(3)
        i=3, print 2, call main(2)
            i=2, print 1, call main(1)
                i=1, if(i--) is false, returns
            returns
        returns
     returns
returns
```